Duplicate kernel logs during boot on Debian trixie
On Debian testing/amd64 (future version trixie) with Linux kernel 6.6.15-amd64, during the boot, I have duplicate kernel messages on my console:

"normal" logs prefixed with timestamp
some duplicate logs without timestamp displayed in light blue color !

The seconds ones are not present in the past and are now displayed by default after a (relatively) recent update.
How to disable these duplicate boot logs and keep only the "normal" ones (displayed on console white on black, prefixed with timestamp) ?
My partial configuration for Grub (bootloader):
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intel_iommu=on"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""


Kernel messages being displayed means the kernel is executing, so GRUB has already done its job and gone away. You don't seem to have any kernel parameters affecting kernel log levels, so console logging is entirely based on kernel defaults, initramfs scripts, and the selected plymouth theme (assuming the plymouth package is installed). What are the contents of your /etc/plymouth/plymouthd.conf file? Is there any common factor in the light blue log messages, e.g. are they all error/warning messages, for example?

My issue was due to the installed plymouth package even if it was not configured to be used during boot (I use only text messages during boot, no graphical animation).
After removal of plymouth package (apt remove plymouth), the duplicate/extra logs for boot are gone : only the kernel ones prefixed with timestamp are displayed.
